# Array PHP Concatenate in one Array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi guys I have this output

```
string(47) "[{"value": "["Mouse","Cable Lock","Headset"]"}]"
```

What I want is like this

```
"[
{
 "value" : "Mouse"
},
{
 "value": "Cable Lock"
},
{
 "value": "Headset"
}
]
"
```

this is my code

```
foreach($_POST['Acc'] as $accessories)
{
   $arrAccesories[] = $accessories;
}

var_dump('[{"value": "'.json_encode($arrAccesories).'"}]');
```

I need it to be encoded because the data I am going to supply must be a string. How to achieve this guys

Comment: What do you get with that code?  What's not working?

Comment: Probably `$arrAccesories[]['value'] = $accessories;`

Comment: what U get from the code is the above data which is this `string(47) "[{"value": "["Mouse","Cable Lock","Headset"]"}]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `value` key in the array:

```
foreach($_POST['Acc'] as $accessories)
{
   $arrAccesories[]['value'] = $accessories;
}
var_dump(json_encode($arrAccesories));
```